# javax.el.MethodNotFoundException with ace:fileEntry component

Tags: jsf-2, el, icefaces

i am trying to use **ace:fileEntry** component to upload files
but i am keep getting errors that action method doesn't exist
here's what i am trying:

1-  **ace:fileEntry component**

```
<h:form>
        <ace:fileEntry id="fileEntryComp"
               label="File Entry"
               relativePath="uploaded"
               fileEntryListener="#{userBean.uploadFile}"/>



        <h:commandButton value="Upload File" action="#{userBean.uploadFile}"/> 



</h:form>
```

2- **UserBean:**

```
public void uploadFile(FileEntryEvent event) {
        FileEntry fileEntry = (FileEntry) event.getSource();
        FileEntryResults results = fileEntry.getResults();
        for (FileEntryResults.FileInfo fileInfo : results.getFiles()) {
            if (fileInfo.isSaved()) {
                log.debug("########### FILE IS SAVED ########");
            }
        }
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /uploadFiles.xhtml @32,81 action="#{userBean.uploadFile}": Method not found: com.myapp.beans.UserBean@2b066718.uploadFile()
```

how to set the method in this case ?
someone will tell me that the method call in xhtml page should take a parameter as in the bean, but i will answer that i did as mentioned in the example here:

http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/FileEntry

please advise.

Comment: With your last edit you've introduced a typo. Please fix it; it's a red herring.

Comment: lots of working hours leads me to such silly mistakes, i added an answer, if you think topic should be deleted, delete it.

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer, I already deleted mine, I was typing an answer in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was that i was using action method with the command button which is not necessary, i just needed to add command button with no action, everything works fine now.

Comment: I am having similar kind of issue where my `FileEntryListener` is not getting called and am not using `action` method, i have posted my code in here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10031300/164299, would appreciate if you have any suggestions